# How can I add Commerce Wishlist share mail template variables from form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-commerce, drupal-9

I am trying to add 2 additional form fields to the Wishlist Share form where the user input will be rendered in the email. I have been able to add the fields to the form, but I am not sure how to add the user's input in the email twig template.

Here is how I have updated the form() function:

```
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    // Workaround for core bug #2897377.
    $form['#id'] = Html::getId($form_state->getBuildInfo()['form_id']);

    $form['to'] = [
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => $this->t('Recipient Email'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

// COMBAK my edit

    $form['sender_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your Name'),
      '#required' => FALSE,
    ];

    $form['sender_message'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your Message'),
      '#required' => FALSE,
    ];

// COMBAK eo my edit

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function actions(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $actions['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Send email'),
      '#submit' => ['::submitForm'],
    ];
    if ($this->isAjax()) {
      $actions['submit']['#ajax']['callback'] = '::ajaxSubmit';
    }

    return $actions;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_wishlist\Entity\WishlistInterface $wishlist */
    $wishlist = $this->entity;
    $to = $form_state->getValue('to');

    // COMBAK: my added vars
    $sender_name = $form_state->getValue('sender_name');
    $sender_message = $form_state->getValue('sender_message');

    $this->wishlistShareMail->send($wishlist, $to, $sender_name, $sender_message);

    $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Shared the wishlist to @recipient.', [
      '@recipient' => $to,
    ]));
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($wishlist->toUrl('user-form'));
  }
```

This is the function that calls the mailHandler that I have updated:

```
public function send(WishlistInterface $wishlist, $to, $sender_name, $sender_message) {
    $owner = $wishlist->getOwner();

    $subject = $this->t('Check out my @site-name wishlist', [
      '@site-name' => $this->configFactory->get('system.site')->get('name'),
    ]);
    $body = [
      '#theme' => 'commerce_wishlist_share_mail',
      '#wishlist_entity' => $wishlist,
      // COMBAK: my added vars
      '#sender_name' => $sender_name,
      '#sender_message' => $sender_message,
    ];
    $params = [
      'id' => 'wishlist_share',
      'from' => $owner->getEmail(),
      'wishlist' => $wishlist,
    ];

    return $this->mailHandler->sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $params);
  }
```

And this is the preprocees function provided by the commerce wishlist module:

```
function template_preprocess_commerce_wishlist_share_mail(array &$variables) {
  /** @var Drupal\commerce_wishlist\Entity\WishlistInterface $wishlist */
  $wishlist = $variables['wishlist_entity'];
  $wishlist_url = $wishlist->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE]);

  $variables['wishlist_url'] = $wishlist_url->toString();

  // COMBAK: my added vars
  //$sender_name = $variables['sender_name'];
}
```

And finally the twig template for the email itself:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Template for the wishlist share email.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - wishlist_entity: The wishlist entity.
 * - wishlist_url: The wishlist url.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<p>
  {% trans %}Check out my wishlist!{% endtrans %}
</p>

<p>
  {% trans %}I use my wishlist for keeping track of items I am interested in.{% endtrans %} <br>
  {% trans %}To see the list in the store and buy items from it, <a href="{{ wishlist_url }}">click here</a>.{% endtrans %}
</p>

<p>
  {% trans %}Thanks for having a look!{% endtrans %}
</p>
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to access the variables I added to the body[] array in the twig template.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your hook template_preprocess_commerce_wishlist_share_mail() executed? Do you get correct value inside $wishlist_url variable. Try to localize your problem. Is problem getting the value or passing it to twig. I.e. try using watch dog to store value of $wishlist_url->toString() and check if it's ok.

Comment: Hi there and thanks! Yes, the $wishlist_url variable is being populated with the correct value. My problem is getting the $sender_name and $sender_message vars into the preprocess template. Unless there is another way of doing that.

Comment: Aha, that's the tricky part. Try using dump() on $variables to see what's available there. Or even better debugger if you have it running. You should able to see object classes so you can find them in code, see what getters they have and how to extract values.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help on this. In my preprocess, I set $variables['vars'] = $variables, then in the theme (email) template, I included {{ dump(vars) }} which didn't return anything... :/ I have devel with vardumper for symphony enabled, but haven't been able to get any output from that anywhere either. Is there any more advice you could give on debugging this? Again, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: If you add something like $variables['test'] = 'test'; to your preprocess function you must be able to print that out from template like {{ test }}. If that's not the case it means that your preprocess function messed up something or it's not called at all. But you said you get correct value in template for $wishlist_url variable, right? You are printing it out correctly?